Transfer hook error: undefined (reading 'tlvData')
I'm having an issue creating a Mint with Transfer Hook. I'm getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tlvData'). This happens when I call createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction, or getTransferHook(mintInfo); after calling an instruction that creates a mint with the Transfer Hook extension. I've checked the mint account and it seems to be created properly, getParsedAccountInfo would return a mint with the extensions I've created.
extensions: [
    { extension: 'transferHook', state: [Object] },
    { extension: 'permanentDelegate', state: [Object] },
    { extension: 'mintCloseAuthority', state: [Object] }
  ],

I first create the mint (ix1):
    let mut extension_types: Vec<spl_token_2022::extension::ExtensionType> = Vec::new();
    extension_types.push(spl_token_2022::extension::ExtensionType::PermanentDelegate);
    extension_types.push(spl_token_2022::extension::ExtensionType::TransferHook);
    extension_types.push(spl_token_2022::extension::ExtensionType::MintCloseAuthority);

    let space = spl_token_2022::extension::ExtensionType::try_calculate_account_len::<
        spl_token_2022::state::Mint,
    >(&extension_types)
    .unwrap();

    // first create the mint account for the new NFT
    let mint_rent = rent::Rent::default().minimum_balance(space);

    let create_idx = solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
        &authority.key,
        &mint.key,
        mint_rent,
        space as u64,
        &spl_token_2022::ID,
    );
    invoke(
        &create_idx,
        &[
            authority.clone().to_account_info(),
            mint.clone().to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
    invoke(
        &extension::transfer_hook::instruction::initialize(
            &spl_token_2022::ID,
            &mint.key(),
            None,
            Some(crate::id()),
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            token_22_program.clone().to_account_info(),
            mint.clone().to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
    invoke(
        &spl_token_2022::instruction::initialize_permanent_delegate(
            &token_22_program.key(),
            &mint.key(),
            &voucher.key(),
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            mint.clone().to_account_info(),
            voucher.clone().to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
    invoke(
        &spl_token_2022::instruction::initialize_mint_close_authority(
            &token_22_program.key(),
            &mint.key(),
            Some(&voucher.key()),
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            mint.clone().to_account_info(),
            voucher.clone().to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
    invoke(
        &spl_token_2022::instruction::initialize_mint2(
            &token_22_program.key(),
            &mint.key(),
            &voucher.key(),
            None,
            decimals,
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            token_22_program.clone().to_account_info(),
            mint.clone().to_account_info(),
            voucher.clone().to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;

    Ok(())

Then I create the extra-account-metas (ix2):
    let binding = mint.key();
    let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
        b"extra-account-metas",
        &binding.as_ref(),
        &[ctx.bumps.extra_account_meta_list],
    ]];

    create_account(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            CreateAccount {
                from: authority.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.to_account_info(),
            },
        )
        .with_signer(signer_seeds),
        account_metas_rent,
        account_size,
        ctx.program_id,
    )?;

    ExtraAccountMetaList::init::<ExecuteInstruction>(
        &mut ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.try_borrow_mut_data()?,
        &account_metas,
    )?;

    Ok(())


After checking the code it looks like the mintInfo you requested is null:
Request the mintinfo like this
      voucherMintInfo = await getMint(
        program.provider.connection,
        voucherMint.publicKey
      );

before calling
const transferHook = getTransferHook(voucherMintInfo);

Looks like you undefined (reading 'tlvData') when the mintinfo is null or undefined.
